# SharePoint files permission management

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a task where I have around 300 files and for those files, I need to assign a certain level of permission based on the person. For example, I have files A, B, C, and D, and only person X can view those files. How can I do this in bulk and not one by one? [sharepoint files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxpWY.png) SP lets you change access by clicking on the file and then by clicking on "i" on the right side of the SharePoint where you will find "manage access", however this only works for one file and you cannot do this with many files.

Comment: Powershell scripting would help you automate this. for example a script with some mechanism to first get a list of files (in csv format) and some extra columns e.g permission level, assigned to etc. then populating the output csv file. Then use that csv file as an input for other script to set item level permissions

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, there is no direct way, you can put the files A, B, C, D that only X users can view into the same folder, then right-click this folder or click 3 dots after this folder, select manage access, enter the folder permission settings page. First Stop Inheriting Permissions, then remove the user who is not allowed to see this folder, and add the appropriate permissions for the X user.

Comment: Hi, I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.